# Vue quickest way to disable and remove value from checkboxes

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a whole bunch of checkboxes (each has their own model) which will be enabled depending on if one checkbox is checked or not. I have found the enabling/disabling part easy, as I just need to place in each checkbox `:disabled="!MasterCheckbox"`

But, if I started filling out those checkboxes, and suddenly I need to disable them, I need the values to go back to false. The only way I'm thinking of doing it right now is a `v-on:change` in the master checkbox, and setting each of the model values for each checkbox to false. For easier tracking, I'm putting them inside a dictionary so I can loop them by keys and set them to false. But I was wondering if maybe there's an easier or more elegant way of doing this. Maybe there's a directive or a prop I can use. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: can you bind the value to the mastercheckbox variable using an "and" operator so the value is ("it's own modal" && !MasterCheckbox) which would be true or false depending?

Comment: That's a good one. I'm going to try it out.

Comment: I tried this                     `<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" v-model="Model"
                           v-bind:value="Model && MasterCheckbox"
                           :disabled="!MasterCheckbox">`

But it did not work. I also tried it with `!MasterCheckbox` in the bind.

Comment: If you are using a dictionary for the bunch of checkboxes - then you can simply reset the dictionary (make it empty) when the master checkbox gets unchecked.

Comment: No, keys in a dictionary should be there any way to bindings work correctly

Comment: Currently, I am not using the dictionary. The models are stand alone. If I couldn't find an easier way to do this, then my alternative was using a dictionary and doing what you said @IVOGELOV

Comment: I doubt there is any easier way.

Comment: v-model overwrites v-bind (https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html) could try 
`v-model="Model && MasterCheckbox"`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is much better than using `v-on:change`, but you can use `watch` like this:

```js
watch: {
    masterCheckbox: function(val, oldVal) {
        if (!val) {
            this.otherCheckbox= val;
            this.andOtherCheckBox = val;
        }
    }
}
```

A little bit shorter though since you don't need to put  `v-on:change` on the master checkbox and your `methods` is a bit *cleaner* (maybe)

Demo here: https://codesandbox.io/s/nameless-cherry-mnvps?file=/src/App.vue